# issues in Coundown timer with IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-countdown

HI am using following coundown timer .i got this plugin from [Keith wood][1]http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html.

Its works fine in all browsers expect IE8 .the timer not working in IE 8

my code is as follow, can any one help me to fix this issues.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


austDay.setSeconds(austDay.getSeconds() + rTime);
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
                until: austDay,
                format: 'MS',
                onTick: function(periods){
                        if(periods[6]==5){
                            alert("Only Five Seconds left");
                        }
                },
                onExpiry:function(){
                        alert("Time Out");
                        window.location.replace(SitePath+'finalpage.html');
                  }
            });
});
```

Comment: Any error on the console?

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method" its the error in console, its show near the line $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({

Comment: What jquery library you use? JQuery support for ie8 ended in jQuery 1.x. Please use Jquery 1.8 or 1.9 if you are using any newer version.

Comment: i am using jQuery v1.11.0.. only

Comment: any problem in chrome?

Comment: problem only in IE 8 and less

Comment: austDay is just variable for date